# how to properly play video in html

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing

We have video files in `amazon-s3` and play them on html in the following format.

```
<video src="<URL>" autoplay/>
```

But I'm not satisfied with it, its nowhere near to how youtube does it.

What is the infrastructure required to stream and play video, where it can buffer and change video quality on the fly?

I'm sure the question is very basic and doesn't have much information.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For Video Buffer You have to Use Java Script:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Buffer</button><br> 

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
  <source src="html.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="html.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  </video>

<script>
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function myFunction() { 
    alert("Start: " + vid.buffered.start(0) + " End: "  + vid.buffered.end(0));
} 
</script>
```